# How to Find Particular Endpoints for Sabre Soap API?

Tags: xml, api, url, soap, sabre

Im completely new to SOAP API's, I've been working with REST API's. I think I've read the documentation of Sabre APIs but i was unable to find the respective endpoints for the SOAP API's.

I tried contacting Sabre but they are not responding to my messages. I was provided the credentials and base url, but i got stuck from the start. Couldn't event find the endpoint for access token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOAP/REST [Endpoints](https://developer.sabre.com/guides/travel-agency/developer-guides/environments)

Token endpoint is [here for SOAP](https://developer.sabre.com/guides/travel-agency/quickstart-guides/get-token)

#### SOAP Endpoint

Certification/Test:

```
https://webservices.cert.platform.sabre.com
```

Production:

```
https://webservices.platform.sabre.com
```

#### REST Endpoint

Certification/Test:

```
https://api.cert.platform.sabre.com
```

Production:

```
https://api.platform.sabre.com
```

#### SOAP Token Endpoint

Token Test Endpoint

```
https://webservices.cert.platform.sabre.com/v3/auth/token
```

Token Production Endpoint

```
https://webservices.platform.sabre.com/v3/auth/token
```

I have no credential but got this response from Postman.
It means test endpoint works.

[image]

You can download Soap APIs postman collection [here.](https://github.com/SabreDevStudio/postman-collections)

[image]

Comment: But that Test Endpoint and Production Endpoint is for REST, not SOAP I guess.

Comment: @AlwaysSunny, I updated SOAP/REST endpoints. If you see the Postman image in Body response, the content is XML format. It means got from  SOAP endpoint response.

Comment: I guess no, in that case the body should be XML SOAP not the raw version

Comment: SOAP API call needs to XML body but this web site Token handling text and XML both possible. The prefix of URL in Token `webservices` means SOAP, The `api` means REST.

Comment: IT worked ,  token url  = https://webservices.cert.platform.sabre.com/v3/auth/token

Comment: I am happy to hear you got it.